# Is $f=0$ if the integral is zero

Tags: real-analysis

If $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and for all $s\in [0,1]$

$$ \int_0^s f(t)dt = 0$$

does it then follows that $f=0$? I can show it for $f \ge 0$ but I am wondering if it is also true if $f$ not positive.

Comment: How do you prove it for $f\ge0$? Perhaps the argument can be adapted to the general case.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I did it by contradiction. But if $f$ is positive and negative the integral can still be zero.

Comment: How by contradiction?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I can use the same argument. If $f \neq 0$ and continuous then $f>0$ or $f<0$ on a delta ball! thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: If $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\ne0$, then $\int_0^a f(x)\,dx\ne\int_0^b f(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 4):

Define $F(x) = \int_0^x f(s)\,ds$.  By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F'=f$. But by your assumption, $F(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.  So $f \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $a:=f(x_0)\ne0$ for some $x_0\in(0,1)$. Then $\frac1a{f(x)}>\frac12$ on some open neighbourhood $x_0\in (x_0-r,x_0+r)\subset(0,1)$ because $f$ is continous. Hence
$$ 0=\frac1a\int_0^{x_0+r}f(t)\,\mathrm dt-\frac1a\int_0^{x_0-r}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_{x_0-r}^{x_0+r}\frac1af(t)\,\mathrm dt\ge \int_{x_0-r}^{x_0+r}\frac12\,\mathrm dt=r>0.$$
Again by continuity, $f(0)=f(1)=0$, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to show it is constant.

imagine the next line with a strike through:

Assume that $f=c$ and $c\ne 0$ and reach a contradiction. Thus proving f=0.

**Fleshing this out:**

$\frac{d}{ds}(\int^s_0f(t)dt)=f(s)$

You know that $f(s)=\frac{d}{ds}(\int^s_0f(t)dt)=\frac{d}{ds}(0) = 0$ for $s\in[0,1]$

So you can ignore the contradiction bit, it doesn't apply. I panicked because the prospect of answer a question first made me rush :p

Comment: You can remove the unnecessary parts.